# Docker: save - produces no output

Tags: docker, save, export, metadata, dockerfile

Fairly new to using Docker..

I pulled an image for Oracle 11g Full.  Created a DB and installed an application into the container.

Once configured correctly, I committed the container which resulted in a 15GB image.

Tested a new container of that image, everything works fine, Oracle services etc. startup automatically and then I just attach and run the application...all good.

I need to upload this onto a server, so my intended approach was:

1) Save container
2) Upload tarball to server
3) Load container

However, when I run the following command:

`sudo docker save --output ~/etlf_961_meta.tar etlf/informatica9.6.1:latest`

it just hangs and produces no output.

The process is active, but no file appears and there is no activity:

`T20 chris # ps aux | grep "docker save"
root     26179  0.0  0.0  91928  5000 pts/14   S+   16:36   0:00 sudo docker save --output /home/chris/etlf_961_meta.tar etlf/informatica9.6.1:latest
root     26201  0.0  0.0 127404 14664 pts/14   Sl+  16:36   0:00 docker save --output /home/chris/etlf_961_meta.tar etlf/informatica9.6.1:latest
root     26277  0.0  0.0  14232   980 pts/0    S+   16:36   0:00 grep --color=auto docker save`

If I use `export` and `import` the process runs fine, a 15GB image is produced and can be imported, however I lose all the ENV and CMD metadata.

Can anyone advise:

1) How to resolve the `save` command, to actually export the container
or
2) How to restore or attach the ENV/CMD metadata (..the dockerfile?) to a exported/imported image?

Much appreciated

Comment: error continues on ubuntu 20 + Docker version 20.10.12

Answer (score 3):

Since you are new to docker I'd like to suggest some things that might make your life easier:

> I committed the container which resulted in a 15GB image.

`commit` is generally not recommended for standard workflows. It is not really reproducible. I would suggest creating a `Dockerfile` using `FROM <oracle image>` and doing the work in the `Dockerfile`.

If you have large datasets you probably want to manage those in volumes or  a host bind mount (aka volume mount).

> I need to upload this onto a server,

The recommended way of doing this is using `docker push` to push to a registry.

> it just hangs and produces no output.

It could be that it's just very slow? You can also check the docker daemon log file to see if there are any warnings.

> How to restore or attach the ENV/CMD metadata (..the dockerfile?) to a exported/imported image?

I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   Reproducing the configuration of the image is not really required.  The initial configuration is fairly complex so it would not be possible to complete all via dockerfile alone.   Commit of a configured image is a more appropriate to this use case.

dockerd does not produce any log output on a save command.  

Ill have a look at pushing instead

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2308

Version 17.12.0-ce-mac46 (21698) solved this problem, image saved successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. I'm stumped by this, but it seems to be the tilde `~`.

This doesn't work (docker version 20.10.8):

```sh
docker save --output "~/img.tar" "my_image"
```

but this does:

```sh
docker save --output "$HOME/img.tar" "my_image"
```

---

EDIT: Hm my bad, apparently tilde substitution is not applied in double quotes, which makes it different from your question.